# Does file position indicator belong to an inode rather than belongs to a file descriptor？

Tags: php, c, file, operating-system

The requirement is "Using multiple processes to write the same file simultaneously and meanwhile read from the file line by line".

```php
<?php

// from PHP doc
// 1. In a+ mode, fseek() only affects the reading position, writes are always appended.
// 2. If handle was fopen()ed in append mode, fwrite()s are atomic 
// (unless the size of string exceeds the filesystem's block size, on some platforms, 
// and as long as the file is on a local filesystem). 
// That is, there is no need to flock() a resource before calling fwrite(); 
// all of the data will be written without interruption.

$fd = fopen('/tmp/mylog.log', 'a+');

function write($fd, $pid, $n = 100) {
    static $num = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        fwrite($fd, $pid . " " .$num++ . PHP_EOL);
        sleep(1);
    }
}


function read($fd) {
    $offset = 0;
    while (true) {
        fseek($fd, $offset);

        $line = fgets($fd);
        $offset += strlen($line);
        echo $line;
    }
}

$processes = 5;
for ($i = 0; $i < $processes; $i++) {
    $pid = pcntl_fork();
    if ($pid == -1) {
        exit('could not fork!');
    } else if ($pid > 0) {
        // parent
    } else {
        // child, 1 reader, 4 writers
        if ($i == 0) {
            echo "start reader...\n";
            read($fd);
        } else {
            echo "start writerr...\n";
            write($fd, posix_getpid());
        }
        exit;
    }
}

// parent
for ($i = 0; $i < $processes; $i++) {
    pcntl_wait($status);
}
```

I understood that child processes will share the file position indicator because they will share the same file descriptor(fd) in which `fopen()`-ed by their parent process. So I have to call `fseek()` in the read process to let it read from a property position.

However, when I try to re-`fopen()` the same file from the read process, I get a new fd as expect, but I still have to call `fseek()`, otherwise the read process can not read anything.

```
function read($fd) {
    $fd = fopen('/tmp/mylog.log', 'rb'); // a new fd
    while (true) {
        $line = fgets($fd);
        echo $line;
    }
}
```

So I think that a file position indicator belongs to an inode rather than belongs to an fd.